# Is it possible to integrate the expression $a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$?

Tags: kinematics, integration

By what I know, there are 3 expression for the acceleration:

$$a=\frac{dv}{dt} \Longleftrightarrow dv=a\,dt$$
$$a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} \Longleftrightarrow a\,dt^2=d^2x$$
$$a=v\frac{dv}{dx} \Longleftrightarrow a\,dx=v\,dv$$

The reason of my question is to obtain the expressions of the movement with constant acceleration, which I don't really know the name in English.

In pdf of the class, they have 3 expression already (methods to obtain them included), which are:

Integrating the 2 sides of the first expression, they obtained $v=v_0+at$;
Equaling this to $\frac{dx}{dt}$, they obtained $x=x_0+v_0+\frac 12at^2$;
Lastly, they integrated the 2 sides of the last expression to obtain $v^2=v_0^2+2a\Delta x$;

What I was curious about was if it possible to do anything with the second expression, so what I did, was as follows:

Put the 2 sides of the expression on integrals, obtaining the equation   $$a\int_0^t \int_0^t dt\,dt=\int_{x_0}^{x} \int_{x_0}^{x} dx\,dx.$$
Integrating the first time to obtain the expression 
$$\int_{x_0}^{x}(x-x_0) dx=a\int_0^t t\,dt,$$
but don't know what to do from here. Does the fact that I obtained $x_0$ on the development of the equation make it impossible to move forward?

Comment: Do you want to prove the projectile motion equation from $F = m a$?

Comment: $a=dv/dt\Rightarrow v=at+v_0$.  $v=dx/dt$...

Comment: Please check the first three equations. It is true that $a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$, but the other two are not correct.

Comment: You cannot treat $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ as a fraction.

Comment: It's my first time using MathJax and I forgot to include $ while writing the formulas, but the document is now edited.

Comment: @ja72 no, just basic constant acceleration movement

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yes, I explain that in my post. What do you want to say.

Comment: You  want Leftrightarrow, $\Leftrightarrow $. And you might be interested in looking up Detexify.

Comment: @Matteo I edited the document, the first one was incorrect but because I made a mistake writing it. The last one, however, is not. You know that $\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$ equals v.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thanks, I will that a look into it.

Comment: @StephenG Please elaborate.

Comment: You have things like $a=d^2x $ which don't make sense.  First integrate to get the velocity, then integrate the velocity to get the position.

Comment: @StephenG hm I understood now, but $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ is not a fraction, so is not $\frac{dx}{dt}$, right? Atleast, in the topic you told me about, they say so. And they use it "as" with the Chain Rule. So, for example, in my first expression, the equivalent notation is not true, right? But in the pdf of the class and in other classes I took they use that notation... May that only be true from an illustrative point of view or what? I am taking an engineering course if that is relevant and throughout the course I already saw one or two examples of "breaking rules" type of thing.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero it's like my teacher represent the second derivate, I don't have fault they use that notation...

Comment: In a lot of modern physics you will find something written like $F^2y$, but this could be read as "perform *operation* $F$ twice on $y$" so $F^2y = F(Fy)$, not "square this" which would be $(Fy)^2$.  This notation is a little context dependent ( like $cos^2\theta$ which does equal $(cos\theta)^2$ ) but you will see it a lot in quantum theory.  In this sense $\frac d {dx}$ is an *operator*.  Experience will make this easier.

Comment: @StephenG I don´t know how that example is of any relevance to our discussion. Besides, no one in their right mind would think that $F^2y$ equals $(Fy)^2$. And what do you mean by operator? Does that means that you can use $\frac{dx}{dt}$ as a fraction but $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ can´t? Thanks for the comparison, but I still don't get it. Anyway, can I do anything else to reach a result?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a prescribed acceleration $a(t)$.

The first integration yields velocity

$$ v(t)  = \int a(t)\,{\rm d}t + C_1 $$

The second integration yields displacement

$$ x(t) = \int v(t)\,{\rm d}t + C_2 =\int \left( \int a(t)\,{\rm d}t \right) {\rm d}t + C_1 t + C_2 $$

So for example, with constant acceleration, starting $t = 0$ with $x_0$ and $v_0$ you have

$$ \begin{cases}
  v(t) = a t + C_1 \\
  x(t) = \frac{1}{2} a t^2 + C_1 t + C_2  \\
  x(0) = x_0 \\
  v(0) = v_0 
\end{cases} $$

Use the last two equations to find $C_1$ and $C_2$.

$$ x(t) = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2 $$

Comment: I feel this would be clearer if you explicitly integrated over a dummy variable, e.g. $t'$, and perhaps put in limits

Comment: Since I have constants of integration it is an indefinite integral. Otherwise I should have stated $$ v(t) -v_0  = \int \limits_0^t a(t)\,{\rm d}t  \\ x(t) -x_0  = \int \limits_0^t v(t)\,{\rm d}t  $$